# Email Service or CRM that checks for duplicate email adresses

Tags: email, crm

I am creating an automated email process for a client who is a chapel. They have people who sign up to receive notifications of a death anniversary.

I exported the contact data as CSV from the database, imported it into Mailchimp and I was about to launch a Mailchimp automation based on a date. Then I realized there are many instances where the same person signed up for multiple death anniversary reminders and MailChimp doesn't allow for duplicate email addresses in one list.

Is there another email service or application that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple [python](http://python.org) script, including either parsing the csv or even querying the db directly, all with the standard libraries, all for free and on just about any platform.

An example of sending an email:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you # Note that you should use bcc rather than to here



# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string()) # you can be a list of strings
s.quit()
```

You probably will wish to send messages as BCC

Comment: What about tracking bounces, etc...

Comment: If you get any bounces the will show up in your inbox - I think that tracking options, (i.e. Notify delivery/read setting),s can be added but be aware that they are client specific.